# apex:relatedList not showed in "NEW" mode

Tags: visualforce, related-list

This is my simple VF page named "RelatedListDetail":

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">  
   <apex:relatedList list="DealRows__r"/>
</apex:page>
```

It´s used to override "New" and "Edit" contact buttons.

[image]

Problem is that when i click the "New" button the related list "DealRows" is not showed.It´s showed instead clicking "Edit" button.
I suppose this s related to "New" record mode.

Is there a way to always show apex:relatedList?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Comment: Are you embedding your VF page into the standard page layout of the Contact object?

Comment: No, using the page  i m overriding "New" and "Edit" contact buttons.

Comment: Sorry, it shows that in your screen shot - my bad. If you're creating a new Contact there won't be any related records. What are you trying to do ultimately?

Comment: Clicking "New" button (on page load) i m inserting a contact record in the apex controller in order to have an ID and let a user add other records "Deal row" in the same page. So i want that the related list will always be showed.

Comment: Ok cool, what I recommend you do is call the function that creates the new Contact from the action attribute in the apex:page tag and have it return a new PageReference('/' + newContact.Id); you might need to do setRedirect(true); on the new PageReference object.

Comment: To clarify, this will create the new Contact and the redirect back round to the same page but in "View" mode rather "New" mode. If you haven't overridden "View" you can always return PageReference('/' + newContact.Id + '/e'); to show the page in "Edit" mode which you have overridden. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok cool, what I recommend you do is call the function that creates the new Contact from the action attribute in the apex:page tag and have it return a new PageReference('/' + newContact.Id); you might need to do setRedirect(true); on the new PageReference object.

To clarify, this will create the new Contact and the redirect back round to the same page but in "View" mode rather "New" mode. If you haven't overridden "View" you can always return PageReference('/' + newContact.Id + '/e'); to show the page in "Edit" mode which you have overridden. :)